# Laravel ordering a relation

Tags: laravel

I have the following query to get a thread and all the messages:

```
$thread = Thread::with('messages.user.zone')
            ->with('participants.user')
            ->findOrFail($id);
```

.

I want to get the thread `messages` ordered by it's `created_at` property `desc`.

Currently the order is from the oldest to the new (asc)

How I can do that? Tried `->orderBy('messages.created_at')` with no luck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
->with(['messages' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}, 'messages.user.zone'])
```

Comment: What about the `.user.zone` of the message?

Comment: use the similar structure for `.user.zone` too.. I think you would just need to replace the `messages` in above query with `messages.users.zone`

Comment: I tried that @jaysingkar, I get `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'order clause'`

Comment: zones is the table name, and each `user` has a relation ship with the `zones` table (I have zone_id in my users table). I'm using `user.zone`  to get the user alongs with zone data

Comment: I can't test it right now but try updated code and please let me know if it works or not.